# How do I configure Docker to always re-install python dependencies?

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, github-actions

I'm working on a large python project spanning multiple repositories. We use Github Actions, Docker and Kubernetes for deployments. I'm fairly new to all of these, including python, so I'm looking for some general advice on how to avoid a recurring problem.

**CONTEXT**

I work with python repos which depend on other repos. In our `requirements.txt`, we install the dependency like `-e git+https://${GH_PAT}@github.com/xyz/foo@main#egg=foo&subdirectory=src`.

In our `Dockerfile`, we have a `RUN` step which calls `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

**PROBLEM**

An issue that I keep running into is, when we have to update one of the dependencies, oftentimes Docker/Kubernetes does not re-pull and re-install the repo.

For example, let's say `bar` depends on `foo`.
First we add some new functions or files to `foo` and push it to main.
Then we add use those new functions in `bar`, build the Docker image, and deploy it to K8s.
However, in K8s, we keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError` even though it is present in the main branch of `foo`.

**FINDINGS**

From what I've found online, the issue may lie in Docker caching. Our Docker is configured with `cache-from: type=gha` and `cache-to: type=gha,mode=max`.

Is there a way to tell Docker to always run `pip install -r requirements.txt`? Or is there some other part of the process that we should improve?

---

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.9

# copy the requirements file into the image
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

# switch working directory
WORKDIR /app

# install the dependencies and packages in the requirements file
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=gh_pat \
  GH_PAT=$(cat /run/secrets/gh_pat) \
  pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=aws_access_key_id \
    --mount=type=secret,id=aws_secret_access_key \
    mkdir /root/.aws && \
    echo "[default]" > /root/.aws/credentials && \
    echo "aws_access_key_id=$(cat /run/secrets/aws_access_key_id)" >> /root/.aws/credentials && \
    echo "aws_secret_access_key=$(cat /run/secrets/aws_secret_access_key)" >> /root/.aws/credentials

# copy every content from the local file to the image
COPY . /app

# configure the container to run in an executed manner
CMD [ "python", "./foo.py" ]
```

Deployment YAML

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foo-deployment
  namespace: foo
  labels:
    app: foo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foo
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - amd64
                - arm64
              - key: eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup
                operator: In
                values: [foo]
      containers:
      - name: matcher-container
        image: ***.***.ecr.us-east-*.amazonaws.com/foo:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
```

Comment: Can you post your Docker file?

Comment: You could try running `docker build` with the `--no-cache` option. Bit hard to hard to understand what this has to do with Kubernetes though. Would be good if you could post your Dockerfile(s) (to see what you are actually building) and you Deployment YAMLs (to see what you are actually deploying).

Comment: Can you add your docker build log? In addition to Karl's suggestion, running pip with the `--no-cache-dir` flag would also be a good bet.

Comment: I don't think either Docker or Kubernetes is seeing any sort of signal that it needs to update anything.  The `requirements.txt` file doesn't seem to change, so Docker will reuse the build from its local build cache, and the Deployment's `image:` also doesn't change, so Kubernetes keeps the existing Pods running a `...:latest` image with old code.  I might actively version the libraries and update the version in the Python dependencies, and use a unique tag per build for your images and in the Kubernetes manifest.